# Filtrer array recursive

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm looking to filter my table recursively with the key "excludeInMenu". I can filter the first table but not the second content in "Items" 
With this code

```
{routes.filter(route => !route.excludeInMenu)
```

Here is the Array I want to filter :

```
const routes: MenuRoute[] = [
  {
    key: 'invoice_show',
    excludeInMenu: true
  },
  {
    key: 'invoice_new'
  },
  {
    key: 'template',
    text: 'Template',
    items: [
      {
        key: 'template_contract',
        excludeInMenu: true
      },
      {
        key: 'template_invoice'
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

I would like to filter it and get this as result :

```
     [
  {
    key: 'invoice_new'
  },
  {
    key: 'template',
    text: 'Template',
    items: [
      {
        key: 'template_invoice'
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Comment: do you want to get a mutated array, or a new one?

Comment: I prefer a non-mutated one

Answer (score 1):

```
function filterItems(items){
 return items.filter(item => !item.excludeInMenu)
}

filterItems(routes).forEach(route => {
 if(route.items){
   route.items = filterItems(route.items)
 }
});
```

Comment: This return me undefined